# Why can't I construct a ThreadPoolExecutor backed by a DelayQueue?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, executors

I'm trying to create a ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
// Thingy implements Delayed and Runnable
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0l, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new DelayQueue<Thingy>());
```

The compiler is saying "cannot find symbol":

```
symbol  : constructor ThreadPoolExecutor(int,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue<Thingy>)
```

but I don't understand — `DelayQueue` implements `BlockingQueue`, so shouldn't I be able to use [this constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue%29)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a generics problem.  You can't use `DelayQueue<Thingy>`, it has to be `DelayQueue<Runnable>` as the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor is not declared to accept queues of sub-types of `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks! Man, generics are crazy.

Comment: I still need help. I changed it to `new DelayQueue<Runnable>()` but that doesn't work either, because `DelayQueue` is declared as `DelayQueue<E extends Delayed>` so apparently I need to specify something which extends `Delayed` but I *also* need to specify `Runnable` — this is crazy. Please help!

Comment: @Avi Good point, I hadn't spotted that.  I think in that case you either have to give up on `DelayQueue` or use an unchecked cast.  If `ThreadPoolExecutor` had been declared to accept `BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable>` it all would have been OK.

Answer (score 1):

`RunnableScheduledFuture` is Runnable and Delayed, but it cannot be cast to  `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. See why at [The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

Have a look to `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, it can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically.

Answer (score 1):

While this is an old question I wanted to post my answer as I was searching for just this solution recently.  It is possible to use a DelayQueue behind a ThreadPoolExecutor, it just takes a bit of code wrapping.  The trick is to get the DelayQueue to present itself as a BlockingQueue.

I started by defining an interface `DR` that extends both `Runnable` and `Delayed`.  Note that the static methods here create instances of the DR (Instance class not shown).

```
public interface DR extends Delayed, Runnable {    
    public static DR make( Runnable r )
    {
        if (r instanceof DR)
        {
            return (DR)r;
        }
        Impl impl = new Impl(r);
        if (r instanceof Delayed)
        {
            impl.expires = ((Delayed) r).getDelay( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
        }
        return impl;
    }

    public static DR make( Runnable r, long expires )
    {
        if (r instanceof DR)
        {
            if (expires == ((DR)r).getDelay( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ))
            {
                return (DR)r;
            }
        }
        return new Impl(r, expires);
    }
}
```

Implementations will should override: `public int compareTo(Delayed o)`, `public boolean equals( Object o )`, and `public int hashCode()`.

Create a class that extends DelayQueue.  This class adds a single method that presents the DelayQuue as a BlockingQueue.  The class returned simply wraps the DelayQueue and uses the `make` methods of the `DR` interface to convert from `Runnable` to `DR` where necessary.

```
public class DelayedBlockingQueue extends DelayQueue<DR>  {

    public BlockingQueue<Runnable> asRunnableQueue() {
        return new BlockingQueue<Runnable>(){
            DelayedBlockingQueue dbq = DelayedBlockingQueue.this;
            public boolean add(Runnable e) {
                return dbq.add( DR.make( e ));
            }

            private List<DR> makeList( Collection<? extends Runnable> coll)
            {
               return coll.stream().map( r -> DR.make( r ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() ) ;
            }

            public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Runnable> arg0) {
                return dbq.addAll(makeList( arg0 ) );
            }

            public void clear() {
                dbq.clear();
            }

            public boolean contains(Object o) {
                if (o instanceof Runnable) { 
                    return dbq.contains( DR.make( (Runnable)o ) );
                } 
                return false;
            }

            public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> arg0) {
                List<DR> lst = new ArrayList<DR>();
                for (Object o : arg0)
                {
                    if (o instanceof Runnable)
                    {
                        lst.add(  DR.make(  (Runnable)o ) );
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return dbq.containsAll( lst );
            }

            public int drainTo(Collection<? super Runnable> c, int maxElements) {
                return dbq.drainTo( c, maxElements );
            }

            public int drainTo(Collection<? super Runnable> c) {
                return dbq.drainTo( c );
            }

            public Runnable element() {
                return dbq.element();
            }                

            public void forEach(Consumer<? super Runnable> arg0) {
                dbq.forEach( arg0 );
            }

            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return dbq.isEmpty();
            }

            public Iterator<Runnable> iterator() {
                return WrappedIterator.create( dbq.iterator() ).mapWith( dr -> (Runnable)dr );
            }

            public boolean offer(Runnable e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
                return dbq.offer( DR.make( e ), timeout, unit );
            }

            public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
                return dbq.offer( DR.make( e ) );
            }

            public Runnable peek() {
                return dbq.peek();
            }

            public Runnable poll() {
                return dbq.poll();
            }

            public Runnable poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
                return dbq.poll( timeout, unit );
            }

            public void put(Runnable e) throws InterruptedException {
                dbq.put( DR.make(e) );
            }

            public int remainingCapacity() {
                return dbq.remainingCapacity();
            }

            public Runnable remove() {
                return dbq.remove();
            }

            public boolean remove(Object o) {
                if (o instanceof Runnable)
                {
                    return dbq.remove( DR.make(  (Runnable)o) );
                }
                return false;
            }

            public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> arg0) {
                List<DR> lst = new ArrayList<DR>();
                for (Object o : arg0)
                {
                    if (o instanceof Runnable)
                    {
                        lst.add(  DR.make(  (Runnable)o ) );
                    }

                }               
                return dbq.removeAll( lst );
            }

            public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> arg0) {
                return dbq.retainAll( arg0 );
            }

            public int size() {
                return dbq.size();
            }

            public Runnable take() throws InterruptedException {
                return dbq.take();
            }

            public Object[] toArray() {
                return dbq.toArray();
            }

            public <T> T[] toArray(T[] arg0) {
                return dbq.toArray( arg0 );
            }                
    };                       
}
```

To use the solution create the `DelayedBlockingQueue` and use the `asRunnableQueue()` method to pass the runnable queue to the ThreadPoolExecutor constructor.

```
DelayedBlockingQueue queue = new DelayedBlockingQueue();
ThreadPoolExecutor execService = new ThreadPoolExecutor( 1, 5, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue.asRunnableQueue() );
```

Comment: Be aware that I tried this solution and it doesn't work.  If your threads aren't busy the ThreadPoolExector will bypass the queue entirely.