# DelayQueue with capacity

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I'm using a DelayQueue. I need to use this so as to only take from the queue when a delay has passed. I also want to enforce a capacity, much like a BlockingQueue. I can't seem to find a Collections implementation of this. Does one exist? If not, what's the best way of implementing it? A basic approach would be to do something like this:

```
public void addSomethingToQueue(Object somethingToAdd){
    int capacity = 4;

    while(queue.size() >= capacity){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    queue.add(somethingToAdd);
}
```

This would mean calling notify / notifyAll each time something was removed. It's quite a small class so that's doable. It doesn't sound great though. And I'm not sure if the wait / notify may cause further problems?

Would it be better to sub-class DelayQueue and mess around with its methods? It feels a bit dodgy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not compose a `BlockingQueue` and a `DelayQueue`? For e.g.:

```
class MyDelayBlockingQueue<T> implements Queue {
    private final DelayQueue<T> delayQ = ...
    private final BlockingQueue<T> blockingQ = ...

    public synchronized void offer(T obj) {
        blockingQ.offer(obj); // this will block if the Q is full
        delayQ.offer(obj);
    }

    public synchronized T poll() {
        T obj = delayQ.poll(); // This will handle the delay
        if (obj != null) {
            blockingQ.poll();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    // ...    
}
```

**EDIT**

The code above will deadlock. If the Q is full, offer will block in a synchronized block, and all future calls to `poll` will block to acquire the intrinsic lock of the Q - causing a deadlock. Try something like instead:

```
public class DelayBlockingQueue<E extends Delayed>
{
    private final DelayQueue<E> delayQ = new DelayQueue<E>();
    private final Semaphore available;

    public DelayBlockingQueue(int capacity)
    {
        available = new Semaphore(capacity, true);
    }

    public void offer(E e) throws InterruptedException
    {
        available.acquire();
        delayQ.offer(e);
    }

    public E poll()
    {
        E e = delayQ.poll();
        if (e != null)
        {
            available.release();
        }
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems a little awkward, but it's probably better than what I had initially. Though with this approach, you would need to override a lot of methods (peek, take, poll, offer, add...).

Comment: That's worth it though. The use of this queue would be much simpler.

Comment: @Spycho the original code I posted will deadlock; I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. That seems a bit more logical as well.

Comment: I shared an implementation for a different question.  Perhaps this is what you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48639437/895732

Answer (score 0):

You may using LRU:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used

Example implementation from Apache Commons:
http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/LRUMap.html

So you don't write this again ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified further, the delay part of the DelayQueue is essential. The LRUMap doesn't do this.